# How do you retrieve an accidentally deleted point in an ArcGIS Web Mapping Application?

Tags: web-mapping, editing, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Hypothetical scenario: I've shared an ArcGIS Web Mapping Application with non-tech-savvy staff members. One of the staff members accidentally deletes a point within the Web Mapping Application.

1. Is it possible to undo this operation within the Web Mapping Application?
2. If not, Can I retrieve the data from the linked database?

Comment: There is an option available to prevent deletion. Go to item details -> edit -> check the prevent deletion box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, and we have run into this problem before, you can not undo this operation in AGO (if anyone has other information I would love to hear it.)  Our solution was to create a versioned environment with the AGO web edits occuring on a child version of the GDB.  That way if field crews screw up some data, which happens more often than you would think, we could easily replace that data with the parent version and go from there.  Here is some data on how to setup versioning, of course this would require ArcSDE.

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t7000000
http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html